# Data not displaying correctly after user logs in through login form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation

The code below is of my user login form. But, after the username and password matches and the page is being redirected, it shows error 'Undefined index in username in [path]'.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "dbreg.php";
$errormsg = array();
$errorcount = 0;
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $errormsg[] = "Enter valid username";
    $errorcount++;
  }
  if(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $errormsg[] = "Please enter password";
    $errorcount++;
}
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
$userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regform WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'");
$useroutput = mysql_fetch_assoc($userquery);

if (empty($useroutput)) {
  $errormsg[] = "Invalid username or password";
  $errorcount++;
}
else {
  $queryoutput = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regform WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' AND userpass = '".$_POST['password']."'");
  $newoutput = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryoutput);
  if (empty($newoutput)) {
    $errormsg[] = "Please enter valid login and password";
    $errorcount++;
  }
  else {
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $newoutput['id'];
    header("Location: http://localhost/classwork2/userprofile.php");
  }
}
}
}

 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <?php
      if (!empty($errormsg)) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($errormsg) ; $i++) {
          # code...
          ?>
          <div style="color:red"><?php echo $errormsg[$i]; ?></div>
          <?php
        }
      }
       ?>
        <table border="1">
            <form name="lognow" id="lognow" action="reglogin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Username</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        <h3>Or</h3>
        <h2>
          <a href="reg1.php">Click Here</a> to Register.
        </h2>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And below is the code to the userprofile.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "dbreg.php";

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM regform WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Hello, " . $row['firstname'] . $row['lastname'] ;

?>
```

Will be kind if anyone can guide me what am i doing wrong. Also if i keep the above code inside an `if(!empty($_POST['username']))` the page displays blank.

Comment: That's because you never did/set `$_SESSION['username'] = "YOUR_USERNAME"` after successful login, you just did `$_SESSION['uid'] = $newoutput['id'];` and redirected the user to *userprofile.php* page.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but there ar lots of usernames and passwords (suppose), then its not possible to use this method i guess, so then what to use? or how should i modify the code?

Comment: I've given a solution below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you never did/set `$_SESSION['username'] = "YOUR_USERNAME"` after successful login, you just did `$_SESSION['uid'] = $newoutput['id'];` and redirected the user to *userprofile.php* page.

So **the solution** is, construct your query based on user's `id`, rather than user's `username`. In *userprofile.php* page, change the query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM regform WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "'";

// your code
```

---

**Sidenote:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. And [this is why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Yes it works now. Thx and i should definitely use mysqli

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag You're welcome. And if you're going start with `mysqli`, I suggest you to read about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) as well.

Comment: Yes of course @Rajdeep i will. Just a question, for 'mysqli' will W3 Schools or any other be a good place?

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag You can Google start from anywhere, but always keep an eye on official documentation, [http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Ok i will. Thank you.